# How can I stop find from searching a dir tree once it finds a match?

Tags: perl, find

This is a variant of "How can I stop find from searching after first result found?" which I posted earlier today but is different enough to warrant a new question (IMO).  It involves the `find` command ant potentially a perl soln if find can't do what I need.

Using `find`, I want to search a dir tree for all instances of dirs with name "out".  Once an instance of "out" is found, I want it to stop searching under that dir but keep searching other paths for "out".

Consider this example...

```
mkdir -p top/a/b/out/c/d/out/e/leaf   
mkdir -p top/a/bb/cc/out/dd/ee/out/ff/gg/out/hh/leaf
```

I want to find...

```
top/a/b/out  
top/a/bb/cc/out
```

... but no other instances of "out".

Also, I want it to stop searching (wasting time) once it hits an instance of "out" in a path.

I am going to run this in perl, so I suppose I could get creative and write some recursive func to do this.  And so I will also tag this with question with "perl" should that be the eventual solution.

Comment: To which `find` are you referring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-prune` action:

```
find top -name out -print -prune
```

This action prevents `find` from recursing into a directory.

Comment: Excellent !   Thanks Duskwuff